# Virtualization: Is there a way to recycle generated containers from nested ItemsControl too?

Tags: wpf, performance, optimization, virtualization, itemscontrol

I have a `DataGrid` with `VirtualizationMode="Recycling"` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` in my ViewModel. It works fine - scrolling and page up/down is fast.

Now I add a further `DataGridTemplateColumn` with an `ItemsControl` in its `DataTemplate`. It is bound to about 15 items (for all rows same count). Now scrolling is much much slower. But if the underlying Collection is Null all is fast again. I assume that the generated ItemContainers in each row will not be recycled.

Is there a way to speed up the whole process or even better recycle all nested controls in the row?

PS: I would prefer a ItemsControl in a DataGridColumn, not a DataGridColumn for each Item in Collection.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AObservableCollection}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding AStringProperty}" Width="40" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Please show the binding for your ItemsControl

Comment: A hack but expose a text property that concatenates items in MyObservableCollection to a string.

Comment: I can't, because I want separate edit, tab navigation, contextmenu, alternativ detailview instead of TextBox and so on ...

Comment: Try ListView.  I don't have the code with me but I have used ListView bound to a collection in a ListView Gridview and full virtualiztion.

Comment: Same problem. Virtualization in ListView is okay but ItemContainers in ListViewItem will be throw away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research I can say: the problem is not the creation of container itself, but the content of container. 15 TextBoxes are heavier then I thought. I've replaced the `TextBox` with `TextBlock` and it was as fast as before.

Because I need editing I changed `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate` into `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate` and created a new CellTemplate with a TextBlock. I switch the templates with:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

so only the selected cell/row shows a `TextBox`.

Of course, now I have new problems with Focusmanagement and Keyboardnavigation. But I think I have to do it this way.